# Foreign key solving

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on creating two different tables with foreign keys on one of them.

I need to relate the sender and receiver from `mailbox` table, to `users.item1`

When I try my code, I get an error of:

> Check the syntax for your version of MySQL

Which I did, I'm running 5.5.25

The manual shows an example which I tried, and I still get an error.

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item1 VARCHAR(32),
    item2 VARCHAR(32),password VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id))";

if ($query = mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    echo "Table users created successfully";
else
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE mailbox(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    item VARCHAR(32), 
    subject VARCHAR(32), 
    item  VARCHAR(64), 
    sender VARCHAR(32), 
    receiver VARCHAR(32), 
    item INT, PRIMARY KEY (id)
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES users(id))";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*..I need to relate the `sender and receiver from mailbox` table, to the `users table item1`..*

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item1 VARCHAR(32),
    item2 VARCHAR(32),
    password VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY(item1)
);

CREATE TABLE mailbox
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    item VARCHAR(32), 
    subject VARCHAR(32), 
    sender VARCHAR(32), 
    receiver VARCHAR(32), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (sender)
        REFERENCES users(item1),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (receiver)
        REFERENCES users(item1)
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a34e47)

*follow-up question: why do you have 3 columns with name `item` on table `mailbox`?*

Comment: would tb_fk# be the variable name i'm trying to relate to in users? The item was a filler

Comment: @user1050632 it is the name of the constraint you have enforced. and what do you mean by variable?

Comment: ha sorry, so not use to mysql, variable i guess i mean field in the table.

Comment: `tb_fk2` and `tb_fk1` are not fields. they are the names of the constraint which you are going to use if you want to drop them. the fields where `mailbox.sender => users.item1` and `mailbox.receiver => users.item1`

Comment: error i still get     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'KEY(userName) )' at line 7Error Creating Table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (sender) REFERENCES users(userName), C' at line 11

Comment: can you post the whoile query you have executed? maybe post it along the question `:D`

Comment: ok i got it, I was missing colons in the correct areas, it works now. thanks so much